# RxJS Waiting for nested observable to filter array data

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, reactivex

Having two `Observables`: `foo` and `bar`.

`foo` will return an `array` of objects as such `[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, ...]` (It will return the entire array (using AngularFire `.list` here))

`bar` has a stored value for each item returned from `foo`. The value is stored as an object as such: `{ id: 2, status: false }`.

What needs to be done here is to call `foo` initially, and in it's map function, I'd like to take out `{ id: 2 }` from the `subscribe()` method if its matching value in `bar`'s response is `false`.

In other terms

1. Watch stream from `foo`
2. `.map` objects and check **each object** status from `bar`
3. `bar` returns an observable with the value of `true` or `false`
4. .`filter` `foo` to take out any object with `status` as `false`

I've tried `combineLatest`, `zip` and other `RxJS` methods but not sure that I am doing this correctly. Could someone please show me the correct way or at least point our which methods I should be exploring?

Appreciate the help!

Thanks.

//

```
.... foo
....... itemId1
....... itemId2

.... bar
....... itemId1: true
....... itemId2: false
```

Upon subscribing to `foo`, the array it returns must be `filtered` to return `itemId1` only, because its `bar` value is `true` (Both are observables, foo and bar ofc)

Comment: Does `foo` emit values one-by-one or the entire array at once? it would be great if you showed your attempts to recreate the desired behavior. I'm guessing, zip or combineLatest should both work.

Comment: Hi @BorisLobanov `foo` emits the entire array.

Comment: And does `bar` emit the array of booleans as well?

Comment: Actually sorry, `bar` will emit one `Object` based on the individual `id` from `foo`. So they need to be mapped together, for each id in the array in `foo` get the latest value from its related object in `bar`. Hope i'm not over complicating this

Comment: So, if foo returns an array of 4 objects, bar will emit 4 values separately?

Comment: @BorisLobanov please see edit

Comment: Can you check out the jsfiddle I made to see if it's doing what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/pp6zpx9u/

Comment: @BorisLobanov yes amazing, but what happens when bar uses `.of` instead of `.from` emitting the full array. (I failed to explain before because now I see that I must subscribe to both Observables and not wait for the first one to finish to subscribe to the second based on each individual id)

Comment: @BorisLobanov I added this `.flatMap(obj => obj);` is this a proper solution?https://jsfiddle.net/pp6zpx9u/4/

Comment: It is! As long as it's doing what you need. :) Do you mind if I post this solution as the answer so you can accept it?

Comment: @BorisLobanov Of course, please do. Thanks appreciate the help.

Comment: glad to help! good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that gets the job done:

```
foo = Rx.Observable.of([
  {id: 1, data: 'foo1'}, 
  {id: 2, data: 'foo2'}, 
  {id: 3, data: 'foo3'}, 
  {id: 4, data: 'foo4'}, 
  {id: 5, data: 'foo5'}, 
  {id: 6, data: 'foo6'}
]);

bar = Rx.Observable.of([
  {id: 1, status: false}, 
  {id: 2, status: true}, 
  {id: 3, status: true}, 
  {id: 4, status: false}, 
  {id: 5, status: true}, 
  {id: 6, status: false}
]).flatMap(obj => obj);

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(foo, bar)
    .filter(([foo, bar]) => bar.status)
    .map(([foo, bar]) => foo.find(obj => obj.id === bar.id))
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Comment: Question, please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/pp6zpx9u/5/ now it returns `undefined` since I added a non existing key. What is a good work around for this? Appreciate if you can help. Thanks